# Android: Getting arrayList elements by index

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have my two arraylist and I have merged their data like this

```
    ArrayList prayerNames={Fajar,Zohar,Asar,Magrib,Isha};

    ArrayList prayerTime={4:04am,2:58pm,4:20pm,5:09pm,8:10pm}

    ArrayList<String> mergedList= new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<prayersTime.size();i++){
     mergedList.add(prayerNames.get(i)+""+prayerTimes.get(i));
     }
     fajarText.append(mergedList.get(0));
     zoharText.append(mergedList.get(2));
     asarText.append(mergedList.get(4))
```

But now when I want to get data from merged list with specific index my activity got stops.
Need Help

Comment: post your logcat error log...

Comment: probably type mismatch, but you have to post your logcat

Comment: the entered values are unique means,  why should you use HashMap?

Comment: Thanks to all of you...but I fixed it, the error was in append...used setText..:)

Answer (score 1):

Your ArrayList initialization is not correct. Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> prayerNames = new ArrayList<String>();
prayerNames.add("Fajar");
prayerNames.add("Zohar");
prayerNames.add("Asar");
prayerNames.add("Magrib");
prayerNames.add("Isha");

ArrayList<String> prayerTimes = new ArrayList<String>();
prayerTimes.add("4:04am");
prayerTimes.add("2:58pm");
prayerTimes.add("4:20pm");
prayerTimes.add("5:09pm");
prayerTimes.add("8:10pm");

ArrayList<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < prayerTimes.size(); i++) {
    mergedList.add(prayerNames.get(i) + "" + prayerTimes.get(i));
}

fajarText.append(mergedList.get(0));
zoharText.append(mergedList.get(2));
asarText.append(mergedList.get(4));
```

Comment: Actually my array was initialized and it was getting data from another class, so it was not the problem. I had resolved the error because the error was in append ,I dn knw why it was not allowing .I used setText rather than append. But seriously Thank u so much for your answer..:)